# How to pass a value to bootstrap modal in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I want to pass one value to my bootstrap modal. In angular2 app. How can I achieve this?. This is my code

```
<button href="" class="ui red button" 
        [attr.data-index]="i"  
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#deleteVersion" 
        data-backdrop="static">Delete</button>

<confirm-dialog [id]="'deleteVersion'" [title]="'Delete Version'" [content]="'Do you want to delete this version ?'" [positiveCall]="deleteVersion.bind(this)"></confirm-dialog>

@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirm-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  id: String;
  @Input()
  title: String;
  @Input()
  content: String;
  @Input()
  positiveCall: Function;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  yes() {
    this.positiveCall = this.positiveCall || function () { };
    this.positiveCall();
  }

}
```

I want to pass index in `ngFor`, Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you using your modal? Are you just using it the normal way you do in Bootstrap, or did you create some ModalService/ModalComponent type behavior in your Angular code?

Comment: more info please ?

Comment: I am using normal bootstrap model, with custom component

Comment: where are you using the `ngFor`? add that code in the question description.

Comment: I want to delete an item in ngFor, i want `id` or `index` from ngFor

Comment: from `ngFor`, you can get teh index like this: `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"` ... if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Faisal, no i want to pass that index to my modal

Answer (score 1):

Set a component property `selectedIndex`, and on click of the button that opens the modal, set that value to the proper index.

You are missing an `ngFor` in your code, so just assume that the `i` in `(click)="selectedIndex = i"` is derived from the `i` in `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`

```
<button href="" class="ui red button"  
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#deleteVersion" 
        data-backdrop="static" 
        (click)="selectedIndex = i">Delete</button>

<confirm-dialog [index]="selectedIndex" [id]="'deleteVersion'" [title]="'Delete Version'" [content]="'Do you want to delete this version ?'" [positiveCall]="deleteVersion.bind(this)"></confirm-dialog>

@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirm-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  id: String;
  @Input()
  title: String;
  @Input()
  content: String;
  @Input()
  positiveCall: Function;

  selectedIndex: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  yes() {
    this.positiveCall = this.positiveCall || function () { };
    this.positiveCall();
  }

}
```

Comment: How can i pass more than one value

Comment: Instead of passing in `[index]` like in my example, maybe create an object and pass the whole object in as a `[data]` @Input or something. That object can contain your index and any other pieces of information you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the index in an `ngFor` you can just access it by assigning variable to `index`

`<div *ngFor="let item of items; let j = index;"></div>`

Comment: i want to pass that index to my modal

Comment: you should be able to pass it in by just using `j` as a parameter, 

P.S: I still cannot see where / how you're implementing your `*ngFor`. Please do add it to your code.